# I am trying to get the value of a variable in javascript using webbrowser1 in vb 20017. I cannot get my browser to recognize the function

Tags: vb.net, jscript

JS function:

```
 (function () {
    //fix to dismiss tooltips of iOS Safari
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) { 
        $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }
})();
function getOrderProgressBar(orderNumber) {
    $('#order-status-container').hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/GetOrderProgressBar',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            orderNumber: orderNumber
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                var activeStepTitle = "";
                var stepsFraction = "";
                $(".order-progress-bar-container").empty();
                var html = '<div class="order-progress-bar" data-current-step-index="' + data.CurrentActiveStepIndex + '" data-current-step-description="' + data.CurrentActiveStepDesctiption + '">';
```

I am needing to get the value of the last line "data.CurrentActiveStepDescription"  I have tried several different ways to put the value out but cannot get the program to recognize the function.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!  Thank you

Comment: Can you debug on the server-side to see if you are actually hitting the ````GetOrderProgressBar```` WebMethod?

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  I was able to figure out how to get the information using InStr(curelement.outerhtml, "data-current-step-index=") and then just reading the information from there.